# Homebrew Bundle failed! Error: Cask 'font-dejavu' is not installed

Tags: drake

FYI -- Running `drake/setup/mac/install_prereqs.sh` this morning resulted in

```
Using robotlocomotion/director
==> Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/dejavu/dejavu-fonts-ttf-2.37.zip
Already downloaded: /Users/russt/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/d627008ddad0942dbf3f0979ce370923362db0b1c087521b0fce86fb9798d74c--dejavu-fonts-ttf-2.37.zip
==> Verifying SHA-256 checksum for Cask 'font-dejavu'.
==> Installing Cask font-dejavu
Error: It seems there is already a Font at '/Users/russt/Library/Fonts/DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf'.
==> Purging files for version 2.37 of Cask font-dejavu
Installing font-dejavu has failed!
Using bazel
Using diffstat
Using doxygen
Using freetype
Using kcov
Using llvm@6
Using patchutils
Homebrew Bundle failed! 1 Brewfile dependency failed to install.
russt@air drake % brew cask uninstall font-dejavu
Error: Cask 'font-dejavu' is not installed.
```

I've decided to post my process here in case others experience the same and feel stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Manually deleting the offending files and re-running the installer got me past it:

```
% rm /Users/russt/Library/Fonts/DejaVu*.ttf
% ./setup/mac/install_prereqs.sh
```

(albeit still with an appearance by our old friend `ERROR: botocore 1.15.41 has requirement docutils<0.16,>=0.10, but you'll have docutils 0.16 which is incompatible.`, which I am ignoring.)

Answer (score 1):

As of https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/13098 the install_prereqs script now does `/usr/local/bin/brew cask uninstall font-dejavu-sans` to automatically resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I had reported the problem at https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/13071#pullrequestreview-394664853.

My solution was `brew cask uninstall font-dejavu-sans` but it's essentially doing the same thing as `rm $HOME/Library/Fonts/DejaVu*`.

I've added a link to this SO entry in [#13071](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/13071).